# Dynamic Image views For User To see Pics

Tags: android, gallery, image-gallery

Trying to make my application give a cooler look am thinking of this. The user clicks a button on an xml and as a result of this a dynamic image gallery viewer comes in front of the user. Like we have in iphone for changing songs. It could include an arrow to the left and right for the user to see the next or previous picture or the user can just use the finger to move to the next picture. I hope am sketching the right picture to the experts here. is it possible to have such a view in android?can i get any running examples?

Comment: Android gallery [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/) and view pager [link](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) of course you can create own view.

Comment: you can use the gallery widget or view pager in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the gallery option or view flipper
 for gallery try this link

```
 http://mobisoftinfotech.com/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/
```

for viewflipper

```
http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example/
```